# Plantillas en C++ (Consulta de sintáxis)

Tags: c++, clase, template

Estoy empezando a aprender como usar Plantillas en C++, y resulta que me dan un código para buscar el numero mayor. Mi duda es que no encuentro donde me puedan explicar para que sirve este extracto del código: "`T Pair <T> :: bigger()`"

Aqui les dejo el codigo completo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Pair {
    private:
        T first, second;
    public:
        Pair (T a, T b):
        first(a),second(b){}
    T bigger();
};

template <class T>
T Pair <T>::bigger(){
    return(first>second ? first : second);
}

int main(){
    Pair <int> obj(11,22);
    cout<<obj.bigger()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu clase no fuese template la función luciría así:

```
class Pair
{
public:
 int bigger();
};

int Pair::bigger(){
   return(first>second ? first : second);
}
```

Donde se ve que hay que indicar que la función pertenece a la clase. Si no se añadiese `Pair::` el compilador entendería que está compilando una función individual y no tendrías acceso a `first` y a `second`.

El problema es que al convertir la clase a plantilla la declaración se complica:

```
template <class T> // 1
// 2       3
   T Pair <T>::bigger(){
     return(first>second ? first : second);
   }
```

Y su explicación es la siguiente:

1. Dado que los templates utilizan tipos genéricos es necesario especificar al inicio de la función cuales van a ser esos tipos (en este caso uno llamado `T`)
2. La función retorna nuestro ya famoso tipo genérico `T`. Sin la declaración anterior el compilador no sabría qué es `T`.
3. Aquí estamos indicando que la función pertenece a una clase de tipo plantilla. Esta parte es importante porque como verás en el futuro las plantillas pueden especializarse y es aquí donde se indica la especialización... Para evitar que el compilador se haga un lío.

Comment: Excelente respuesta y muy clara, gracias por la ayuda amigo.

Answer (score 3):

Como dijo *Jack el Destripador*, vamos por partes:

```
  ...
  T bigger( );
};
```

Es una *declaración*; sirve para indicar al compilador que existe una función con un determinado nombre, argumentos, y valor de retorno; en este caso, de nombre `bigger`, sin argumentos (`void`), y que retorna un valor de tipo `T`, que es el tipo usado en la plantilla. El *cuerpo* de dicha función se indicará después, bien en el mismo archivo, bien en otro archivo distinto.

```
template< class T > T Pair< T >::bigger( ) {
  return ( first > second ? first : second );
}
```

Esto es la *implementación* de la función declarada con anterioridad. Le indica al compilador cual es el *cuerpo* de la función. En este caso, la sintaxis de las plantillas *emborrona* un poco al código:

```
template< class T > T Pair< T >::bigger( ) {
```

Es el **nombre completo**, incluyendo la clase, de la función que vamos a implementar; ha de ser **el mismo** que cuando se definió, puesto que se pueden haber *declarado* varias funciones en varias clases; como se definió en una *plantilla*, el *nombre completo* ha de incluir los parámetros de dicha plantilla.

```
  return ( first > second ? first : second );
}
```

Es el *cuerpo* de la función, el código real que se ejecutará.

El mismo código, pero usando el tipo `int`, sin plantillas:

```
class Pair {
private:
  int first, second;

public:
  Pair( int a, int b): first( a ), second( b ) { }
  int bigger( );
};

int Pair::bigger( ) {
  return first > second ? first : second;
}
```

Y ahora, el mismo código, sin plantillas, pero *implementando* la función dentro de la declaración de la clase:

```
class Pair {
private:
  int first, second;

public:
  Pair( int a, int b): first( a ), second( b ) { }
  int bigger( ) {
    return first > second ? first : second;
  }
};
```

En C++, el *implementar* la función **al mismo tiempo** que la declaramos tiene como consecuencia el uso implícito del atributo `inline` para esa función.

Esta técnica se utiliza cuando, por cualquier motivo, *no es posible* indicar el cuerpo de la función en el mismo momento de la declaración, porque utilizamos algo que *no está disponible* en el momento de declarar, como alguna variable o algún tipo.

También es la base del uso de los más que famosos `#include`, en los cuales se *declaran* funciones que **no** implementamos nosotros ni se incluyen en dichos archivos, sino que están disponibles en otros ficheros y que serán *enlazadas* a nuestro código. Es un proceso que se realiza **siempre**, aunque no lo indiquemos directamente.

Una consecuencia de lo anterior es que las *implementaciones* de funciones **no es obligatorio** que estén en el mismo archivo; una vez que informemos al compilador de que la función existe, nos permitirá usarla (comprobando los tipos) en cualquier punto de nuestro código *posterior* a dicha definición. Durante un proceso posterior, el *enlazado*, ya se buscarán las implementaciones.

Comment: Todo lo que dices es correcto.. pero te ha quedado un pelin largo... :D Te doy +1 pero opino que una versión "resumida" le vendría bien al OP ;)

Comment: Thx. Estoy de acuerdo, es algo largo, pero ... ¿ que omito ? solo le doy pistas ... que busque más info si quiere :-)

Comment: Muy clara explicación, me ha costado un poco entenderla al 100%, me has ayudado a solventar dudas, gracias.